# Standard way to implement a buffered stream that flushes at a constant interval?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, boost-iostreams

I'm simulating packets from a source that produces packets at a given packet/second interval. I want to make a stream class that operates like an `ostream` object, allowing `operator<<` to be used to output things through it, but with the caveat that each value inserted should be released from the buffer to a file descriptor, in order, at a specified interval.

So, for instance, I might have a socket with file descriptor `sockfd` and say:

```
MyBuffer buffer(sockfd, 1000); //Interval of 1000 milliseconds
buffer << 1 << 2 << 3;
```

and the output would be timed such that it would output

```
1
<1 second gap>
2
<1 second gap>
3
```

to the socket. I'm looking at Boost.Iostreams right now, would that be a good solution? Is there some magical phrase I can google that describes this problem that I'm not aware of?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Brad

Comment: Do you want to release *characters* one at a time or *objects inserted into the stream* one at a time?

Comment: Are insertions happening concurrently while packets are output? If so, what happens when the stream becomes empty for >1sec, and then becomes not empty again? Is the next packet transmitted immediately, or at the next 1sec interval?

Comment: @templatetypedef it would be objects

Comment: @emile it would be happening concurrently, so I think the only solution would be like templatetypedef suggested, which is a polling thread. I think I was just approaching it wrong-headedly.

Comment: In that case, the queue in template's solution would have to be thread-safe, to avoid race conditions when a packet is input simultaneously while another is output. If you make the producer and consumer threads acquire a mutex while manipulating the queue, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option for doing this that's completely orthogonal to building a custom streams class would be to maintain a queue of strings that's polled by a thread every second.  Each time the queue is polled, the thread reads out the first element and sends it across the network.

This doesn't use the streams library, but I think that might be what you want.  Internally, most streams just glob together all the input they get into a mass of text, losing the information about which parts of the text correspond to each object you inserted.

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned this the first time around, but please be sure to use the appropriate synchronization on this queue!  You'll probably want to use a mutex to guard access to it, or to use a clever lock-free queue if that doesn't work.  Just be sure not to blindly read and write to it from multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Should the 1000ms be asynchronous ? If not, you could put a Sleep(1000) in your stream's operator<<. Depending on what you're trying to do, it could suit you.